# Combine two queries that both categorize the data based upon the results

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, categorization

I am trying to combine two different queries that are basically serving the same function. The results of each query are being categorized based upon the results of one column. When I have tried to combine them, I receive an error stating there is an arithmetic overflow.

Below is the first line of code.

```
   select t1.Lives_Category,
   Count(t3.clean_ft_ee_cnt) "MVP Number of Clients",
   sum(t3.clean_ft_ee_cnt) as "MVP Sum of Lives"
   from [mvpGA].[mvp_client_data_t] t3
   join
   (
         select * from 
         (values ('1-9 Lives',1,9),
                 ('10-49 Lives',10,49),
                 ('50-199 Lives',50,199),
                 ('200-499 Lives',200,499),
                 ('500-1,9999 Lives',500,1999),
                 ('2,000+ Lives',2000,100000000),
                 ('Total Lives',0,100000000),
                 ('500+ Lives',500,1000000000),
                 ('Unknown Lives',0,0)
         )
         as Base_Table (Lives_Category,MinCnt,MaxCnt)
   ) t1 
   on t3.clean_ft_ee_cnt between t1.MinCnt and t1.MaxCnt
   where t3.mvp_rpt_id > 1399
   and t3.clean_do_not_use_ind is NULL
   and t3.clean_client_indv_flag = 'Group'
   group by t1.Lives_Category
```

the results then show as:

```
Lives_Category   | MVP Number of Clients | MVP Sum of Lives
-----------------------------------------------------------
1-9 Lives        | 7565                  | 33845
10-49 Lives      | 7996                  | 191190
50-199 Lives     | 6820                  | 680157
200-499 Lives    | 2281                  | 683971
500-1,9999 Lives | 1510                  | 1424911
2,000+ Lives     | 672                   | 8282279
                 |                       |  
Total Lives      | 26929                 | 11296353
                 |                       |  
500+ Lives       | 2182                  | 9707190
                 |                       | 
Unknown Lives    | 85                    | 0
```

Second line of code is here and is the same structure, the difference is the where clause.The results of the two columns "Number of Clients" and "Sum of Live" will need to be their own columns.

```
    select distinct a1.Lives_Category as "Lives Category",
    count(t2.clean_ft_ee_cnt) as "Number of Clients",
    sum(t2.clean_ft_ee_cnt) as "Sum of Lives"
    from [mvpGA].[mvp_client_data_t] t2
    join 
    (
    select * from 
    (values ('1-9 Lives',1,9),
                 ('10-49 Lives',10,49),
                 ('50-199 Lives',50,199),
                 ('200-499 Lives',200,499),
                 ('500-1,9999 Lives',500,1999),
                 ('2,000+ Lives',2000,100000000),
                 ('Total Lives',0,100000000),
                 ('500+ Lives',500,1000000000),
                 ('Unknown Lives',0,0)
         )
         as Base_Table (Lives_Category,MinCnt,MaxCnt)
     ) a1 
     on t2.clean_ft_ee_cnt between a1.MinCnt and a1.MaxCnt
     where t2.mvp_rpt_id = 1400
     and t2.clean_mvp_rpt_breakout = 'Fargo'
     and t2.clean_do_not_use_ind is NULL
     and t2.clean_client_indv_flag = 'Group'
     group by a1.Lives_Category
```

I would like the end result to be 5 columns. See structure below.

Lives_Category | MVP Number of Clients | MVP Sum of Lives | Number of Clients | Sum of Lives

So to recap, the results are categorized the same as shown in the Lives_Category.....but I would like to have 5 columns. Note: the queries are technically calculating off of the same table, there are just different where clauses.

Comment: I am confused. You want 5 columns. What are the two extra columns for? What do you mean 'Sharing'? You got errors when you ran your first query but you still got the result? Could you improve your post so that more users can understand your question and help you?

Comment: @GenWan I updated the description above. Please let me me know if it is still confusing and I can update more items if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know enough about your data to know if you should use a inner, left, right, or full join. So you should modify the join to suit your situation, but this should get you on the right track. Basically, I put each your your select statement in a subquery and join on the common field, "Lives Category".

```
SELECT    COALESCE(x.[Lives Category], y.[Lives Category]) AS [Lives Category]
        , x.[MVP Number of Clients]
        , x.[MVP Sum of Lives]
        , y.[Number of Clients]
        , y.[Sum of Lives]
FROM      (
              SELECT   t1.Lives_Category         AS [Lives Category]
                     , COUNT(t3.clean_ft_ee_cnt) AS [MVP Number of Clients]
                     , SUM(t3.clean_ft_ee_cnt)   AS [MVP Sum of Lives]
              FROM     mvpGA.mvp_client_data_t AS t3
              JOIN     (
                           SELECT *
                           FROM   (
                                      VALUES ('1-9 Lives', 1, 9)
                                           , ('10-49 Lives', 10, 49)
                                           , ('50-199 Lives', 50, 199)
                                           , ('200-499 Lives', 200, 499)
                                           , ('500-1,9999 Lives', 500, 1999)
                                           , ('2,000+ Lives', 2000, 100000000)
                                           , ('Total Lives', 0, 100000000)
                                           , ('500+ Lives', 500, 1000000000)
                                           , ('Unknown Lives', 0, 0)
                                  ) AS Base_Table (Lives_Category, MinCnt, MaxCnt)
                       )                       AS t1 ON t3.clean_ft_ee_cnt BETWEEN t1.MinCnt AND t1.MaxCnt
              WHERE    t3.mvp_rpt_id > 1399
                       AND t3.clean_do_not_use_ind IS NULL
                       AND t3.clean_client_indv_flag = 'Group'
              GROUP BY t1.Lives_Category
          ) AS x
FULL JOIN (
              SELECT   DISTINCT
                       a1.Lives_Category         AS [Lives Category]
                     , COUNT(t2.clean_ft_ee_cnt) AS [Number of Clients]
                     , SUM(t2.clean_ft_ee_cnt)   AS [Sum of Lives]
              FROM     mvpGA.mvp_client_data_t AS t2
              JOIN     (
                           SELECT *
                           FROM   (
                                      VALUES ('1-9 Lives', 1, 9)
                                           , ('10-49 Lives', 10, 49)
                                           , ('50-199 Lives', 50, 199)
                                           , ('200-499 Lives', 200, 499)
                                           , ('500-1,9999 Lives', 500, 1999)
                                           , ('2,000+ Lives', 2000, 100000000)
                                           , ('Total Lives', 0, 100000000)
                                           , ('500+ Lives', 500, 1000000000)
                                           , ('Unknown Lives', 0, 0)
                                  ) AS Base_Table (Lives_Category, MinCnt, MaxCnt)
                       )                       AS a1 ON t2.clean_ft_ee_cnt BETWEEN a1.MinCnt AND a1.MaxCnt
              WHERE    t2.mvp_rpt_id = 1400
                       AND t2.clean_mvp_rpt_breakout = 'Fargo'
                       AND t2.clean_do_not_use_ind IS NULL
                       AND t2.clean_client_indv_flag = 'Group'
              GROUP BY a1.Lives_Category
          ) AS y ON x.[Lives Category] = y.[Lives Category];
```